# How to remove the first row of each element in a list

Tags: r, list

I know how to remove the first column from each element in a list in R, but how do I remove the first row?

```
ldf1<-lapply(ldf, "[", -1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
ldf1 <- map(ldf, ~ .x %>% 
                     slice(-1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
ldf1 <- lapply(ldf, tail, -1)
```

Using `tail()` with a negative number will remove that many rows from the top of the data.frame.

But you could also pass an empty parameter to `lapply`

```
lapply(ldf, `[`, -1, )
```

or use an anonymous function

```
lapply(ldf, function(x) x[-1, ])
```